# What is Day One Profit and why is it a matter/important?

Tags: accounting, banking-regulations

I am aware that Day One Profit is something that all banks calculate and report etc. I have not managed to find a free comprehensive review of it, what is it, how it's calculated, who and why requests to calculate it, what are its implications etc. Most are either too technical or too specific considering prior knowledge of the concept. So, can anyone concisely elaborate on this topic and mainly its functional implications for all stakeholders, banks, clients, central banks, etc?

Answer (score 2):

Day One Profit (DOP) refers to the immediate gain or loss that a bank or financial institution realizes upon entering into a financial transaction, such as a derivatives contract or a loan. It's an important metric because it provides insight into the profitability and risk of a particular transaction at the very beginning.

DOP is calculated by comparing the fair value of a financial instrument with its transaction price on the inception date. The difference between these two values represents the Day One Profit or Loss. Fair value is typically determined using market data and valuation models.

For banks, DOP helps them understand the immediate profitability of a transaction. This information can be useful in managing their overall portfolio and risk exposure. Banks need to comply with accounting and regulatory standards related to the recognition and disclosure of Day One Profits. High DOPs might indicate that the bank is taking on too much risk or not pricing its products appropriately.

DOP provides a measure of pricing transparency in the financial market, as it shows how closely the transaction price aligns with the fair value of a financial instrument.

Comment: As a bank shareholder  I would like to know if the bank is pricing is pricing its products correctly, based on well estimated cost plus a reasonable profit. Disclosing Day One profit is a first step towards alllowing this kind of judgement (although it requires other info as well, such as what happened after the first day). For example if the actual profit is always less than the D1P it suggests poor estimates of actual costs, or poor execution during the implementation.